# Подключиться к отдельному стобцу

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Понимаю что вопрос совсем простой, но что то не могу решить проблему, есть база данных в phpmyadmin в общем есть столбец uch, изначально задано что у всех пользователей стоит значение 0, но я хочу сделать что к примеру если указано значение один то выдать текст к примеру "Облом", просто не знаю как подключиться к одному столбцу

```
<?php 
include_once("bd.php"); //подключение дб 
**$query3 = ("SELECT uch FROM users");
$sql = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=zapis4.php'>";
}**
$query2 = ("SELECT * FROM uchastniki WHERE login='$login'");
$sql = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=zapis2.php'>";
}
else{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(nomer) FROM uchastniki"); //кол-во записей в бд 
$count = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if($count[0] < 16)
{
$query = "INSERT INTO uchastniki (id, login, password, email, community, bals, uchtour, wintour, winmatch) SELECT id, login, password, email, community, bals, uchtour, wintour, winmatch FROM users WHERE id = $id_user"; //регистрация пользователя 
mysql_query ( $query ); 
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=zapis1.php'>"; 
}
else {
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=zapis3.php'>"; 
}}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Вот то что пометил звёздочками.

```
$query3 = ("SELECT uch FROM users");
    $sql = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=zapis4.php'>";
    }
```

Он не видит что значение стоит один, и всё равно переносит мои данные в другую таблицу, а мне надо что если стоит значение больше нуля чтобы он не переносил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И в чем проблема?

Запрос:

```
SELECT uch FROM table WHERE uch > 0
```

PHP:

```
//Обработка результатов запроса    
$echo "Облом";
```

Comment: хочу что бы выдавало на сайте, мне именно нужен код обработки на сайт

Comment: Обновил вопрос  в самом верху

Comment: Вставьте туда еще одну проверку в запрос SELECT uch FROM users WHERE DATALENGTH(uch) > 0 если хотите игнорировать пустые строки.

Answer (score 0):

Уточните, когда и при каких условиях вы хотите "выдавать облом"? 
На данный момент - могу лишь сказать, что вы можете выставить у поля значение NOT NULL и при попытке оставить это поле пустым MySql будет показывать ошибку.

Comment: например если стоит значение 1, то просто к примеру выдавать "облом", если стоит значение 2 то например выдавать "Не облом", если 0 то ничего не выдавать

Comment: Где вы хотите выдавать это значение? в php скрипте?
Если да, вам правильно подсказали выше 

**SELECT поле FROM таблица;**

И далее работайте со значением этого поля.
А лучше покажите ваш код.

Comment: хочу что бы выдавало на сайте, мне именно нужен код обработки на сайт

Comment: Так покажите кусок кода который у вас уже есть. Потому что ответ зависит от того, как вы работайте с базой данных (через какой интерфейс)

Comment: Обновил вопрос сверху

Comment: SELECT uch FROM users WHERE uch > 0

Comment: всё равно, эффект остался тот же

Answer (score 0):

если я вас правильно понял, вам нужны все записи

в php можно не обрабатывать

если у вас двойственный выбор (например 1 или не 1), воспользуйтесь встроенной mysql функцией IF(condition, true, false):

```
SELECT 
  IF(uch = 1, 'Облом', 'Не облом') AS result 
 FROM users
```

если выбор множественный (например 0, 1 или все остальные цифры), воспользуйтесь оператором CASE :

```
SELECT 
    CASE uch 
      WHEN 0 THEN 'Это ноль'
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Это один'
      ELSE 'Это не ноль и не один'
    END AS result
 FROM users
```

Comment: Мне как раз таки и нужно всё обработать в php,  мне просто нужен обработчик на сайт, если в колонке uch стоит значение 1 то выдавать просто в примеру облом, если стоит ноль то продолжать обработку